# FSTAB automount fail

Tags: fstab, reboot, automount

Hardware: RPI4 + Radxa Quad Sata hat
Version: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1050-raspi aarch64)

GPT partition table with single ext4 partition / disk
I testing it from throught ssh!
After I create the partitions I set in fstab the PARTUUID -s and everything  -i think correctly.
I test it after saving and closing fstab with mount -a before I reboot - everything looks fine.
After reboot i run lsblk but there is nothing mounted.

In the example I show only 1 of my disk  (sda -sda1)

```
~# blkid
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="system-boot" LABEL="system-boot" UUID="5496-E6C8" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="f66f0719-01"

/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="writable" UUID="675ba907-3741-428c-afa4-c00f1b649e3c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f66f0719-02"

/dev/sda1: UUID="df65129a-4044-450b-858b-7e8baedd32b9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7f8bca54-fc26-3c4c-82e4-5cfa0810c134"
```

`fstab`:

```
LABEL=writable  /        ext4   defaults        0 1

LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0       1

PARTUUID=7f8bca54-fc26-3c4c-82e4-5cfa0810c134   /media/disk1  ext4   defaults  0   0
```

```
root@rpi4server:~# mount -a
root@rpi4server:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 465.8G  0 part /media/disk1
mmcblk0     179:0    0  59.6G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  59.4G  0 part /
```

after reboot:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 21 06:35:56 2022 from 166.166.6.12

swordfish@rpi4server:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 465.8G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0  59.6G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  59.4G  0 part /
```

I testing it for a while with other formats but not working. Please help what Iam doing wrong :)
Thanks

```
root@rpi4server:~# lsblk -o NAME,UUID

NAME        UUID
sda
└─sda1      f21e8445-3c18-4411-9af5-fba4b5f74691
sdb
└─sdb1      f45d817c-5fa5-4359-8f6b-a55d4b1eda9a
sdc
└─sdc1      d70c7a23-9033-47a3-a456-5c38d1939255
sdd
└─sdd1      231cee4e-dc11-47c6-b6c2-0bf9caccdc93
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 5496-E6C8
└─mmcblk0p2 675ba907-3741-428c-afa4-c00f1b649e3c
```

---

I restarted the whole process (partitioning, format, mount)
I added `@reboot /bin/mount -a` to crontab  - still not working
Parallel I tried with UUID instead of PARTUUID
But still not mounting automatically...

Comment: please post output of 'lsblk -o NAME,UUID'

Comment: May be it's a timing issue. You could solve that with crontab. Add @reboot /bin/mount -a to crontab.

Comment: Could you please try it with the UUID instead of the PartUUID ?  Somehow like this: UUID=df65129a-4044-450b-858b-7e8baedd32b9   /home/zoltan/disk1       ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,discard,nobh,data=ordered,commit=120          0       2

Answer (score 0):

`PARTUUID=7f8bca54-fc26-3c4c-82e4-5cfa0810c134   /media/disk1  ext4   defaults  0   0`

You can try mounting without PARTUUID and simple mount `/dev/sda1` to `/media/disk1`

`/dev/sda1   /media/disk1  ext4   defaults  0   0`

Comment: Hi, I tried it , the same situation